# Script para quitar likes y eliminar comentarios en facebook

Tags: script, facebook, google-chrome, console

He estado leyendo que hubo un tiempo en había una forma de quitar todos los likes y reacciones a través de tu **Activity log** mediante la consola. Se resolvía haciendo esto:

Íbamos al **Activity Log**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego a la sección, en este caso **comentarios**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Filtrábamos por **año**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pegábamos el siguiente código en la consola de, en este caso, **Chrome**

```
var options = {
  year: '2018', // MIND THE YEAR
  limit: 0 // use 1000 if you want to throttle it
};

function delete_hide_unlike(options) {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#facebook #year_' + options.year + ' ._42fu');
  for (var k = rows.length - 1; k >= options.limit; k--) {
    var row = rows[k];
    var rowButton = row.click();
    var editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('._54nh');
    for (var j = editButtons.length - 1; j >= options.limit; j--) {
      var editButton = editButtons[j];
      if (!editButton) {
        console.log('Nope!');
        break;
      }
      if (editButton.textContent == 'Delete') {
        editButton.click();  // COMMENT OUT IF YOU WANT TO TEST IT OUT WITHOUT ACTUALY DELETING
        console.log("DELETED");
      } else if (editButton.textContent == 'Hidden from timeline') {
        editButton.click();   // COMMENT OUT IF YOU WANT TO TEST IT OUT WITHOUT ACTUALY DELETING
        console.log("HIDDEN");
      } else if (editButton.textContent == 'Unlike') {
        editButton.click();   // COMMENT OUT IF YOU WANT TO TEST IT OUT WITHOUT ACTUALY DELETING
        console.log("UNLIKED");
      } else if (editButton.textContent == 'Remove reaction') {
        editButton.click();   // COMMENT OUT IF YOU WANT TO TEST IT OUT WITHOUT ACTUALY DELETING
        console.log("REACTION REMOVED");
      } else {
        console.log("IGNORED")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

delete_hide_unlike(options);

Luego de eso, una vez presionado enter tendría que salir lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, en mi caso solo dice: `undefined`

¿Alguien tiene idea de como solucionarlo? Cabe aclarar que las imágenes son de carácter ilustrativo, por eso en la `var` del código puse 2018, ya que ese es el año que elegí en mi **Activity log**

Comment: Solo estas declarando una funcion, no ejecutandola. Intenta con `function test() {}` y veras el mismo resultado. Para ejecutar tu funcion escribe `delete_hide_unlike(options);`.

Comment: Pues no, no ha funcionado. Sigue diciendo lo mismo @cavpollo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos cosas:

1. El script está adaptado para la versión antigua de facebook o la "versión clásica". Aún puedes cambiar a esta opción. En la nueva versión todo cambia, los nombres de las clases son distintos por lo que no funcionará nunca el script.
2. Depende de como tengas el idioma. Entiendo que tienes la configuración en inglés sino nunca encontrará cadenas como "Remove reaction", "Delete" o "Unlike" ya que estará en español.

Si cambias estas dos cosas, sí funcionará el script, de hecho, lo ejecutado eliminando `editButton.click();` (para que no me borre nada):

```
var options = {
  year: '2020', // MIND THE YEAR
  limit: 0 // use 1000 if you want to throttle it
};

function delete_hide_unlike(options) {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#facebook #year_' + options.year + ' ._42fu');
  for (var k = rows.length - 1; k >= options.limit; k--) {
    var row = rows[k];
    var rowButton = row.click();
    var editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('._54nh');
    for (var j = editButtons.length - 1; j >= options.limit; j--) {
      var editButton = editButtons[j];
      if (!editButton) {
        console.log('Nope!');
        break;
      }
      if (editButton.textContent == 'Delete') {
        console.log("DELETED");
      } else if (editButton.textContent == 'Hidden from timeline') {
        console.log("HIDDEN");
      } else if (editButton.textContent == 'Unlike') {
        console.log("UNLIKED");
      } else if (editButton.textContent == 'Remove Reaction') {
        console.log("REACTION REMOVED");
      } else {
        console.log("IGNORED")
      }
    }
  }
}

delete_hide_unlike(options)
```

**Conclusión**:

1. Cambia el idioma a inglés.
2. Cambia a la versión clásica donde funciona todavía el script.
3. Ve al "Activity Log" -> "Likes and Reactions"
4. Cambia en el script "Remove reaction" a "Remove Reaction". Ahora es en mayúsculas ambas palabras.
5. Intenta ejecutar el script eliminando lo que te comenté por si acaso, para hacer una prueba.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿Cuál sería la url de la versión clásica?

Comment: Sigue siendo la misma URL. Tienes el enlace de como cambiar a la versión clásica: https://es-es.facebook.com/help/645404059595478

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ha sido tal y como has dicho. Mil gracias